# How do I let Callgrind access my Qt project's source code?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, valgrind, qmake, callgrind

I built a Qt project in Debug mode with Qt Creator, ran Callgrind to generate profiling data and tried loading it into Cachegrind. I noticed that I only see profiling information for Qt classes, so I figured I must have forgotten to turn on a crucial flag.

Qt Creator's `qmake` command looks like this:

```
qmake /path/to/project/MyProject/MyProject.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64 CONFIG+=debug
```

Sample compile output for one file:

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I../Flowchart -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/usr/include -I. -I. -I../Flowchart -I. -o main.o ../Flowchart/main.cpp
```

The `-g` flag is there, so debug information should be available. I verified this by running `gdb` on the executable and trying to look at some random source code with `l`.

The Callgrind command I used was:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./MyProject
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --trace-children=yes --demangle=yes ./MyProject
```

Also depending on the distribution of Linux you may have to make sure that you have the Debug information in the QT libraries you are linking against.